# How can we explain the objective case 'them' in 'I proved them wrong'?

Tags: objective-case

> (1) *I proved them to be wrong.*
>
> (2) *I proved them wrong.*

In (1), the objective case *them* is explained with either [Raising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_(linguistics)#:%7E:text=In%20linguistics%2C%20raising%20constructions%20involve,argument%20of%20an%20embedded%20predicate.) or [Exceptional Case Marking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exceptional_case-marking). The case needs explaining because *them* is not a semantic argument of the verb *proved* but a semantic argument of the embedded predicate *to be wrong*. So the explanation is either that the subject of the embedded predicate is "raised" from the subordinate clause to the main clause, or that the subject of the embedded predicate is exceptionally marked as the object case.

Now, when it comes to sentences like (2), neither explanation can be used, because either Raising or ECM is designed to explain sentences where there is a embedded predicate. Note in (2) that *wrong* itself wouldn't be considered an embedded predicate for the purpose of Raising or ECM. Nevertheless, (2) does have the objective case *them*, which is not a semantic argument of the verb *proved* just as in (1).

How can we explain the objective case *them* in (2)?

Comment: Is it any different to "I painted them green" or "I called them stupid"? In other words, object and object complement. I don't know which framework you want it explained within, so I won't attempt to answer.

Comment: The subject of an infinitive is objective case. If the infinitive marker _to_ and the auxiliary _be_ are deleted by _to be_-Deletion, that doesn't change the case. Why should it? Especially when Raising then places it in precisely the position in the sentence where an objective pronoun ought to be. If you want to explain its presence, you have a multitude of choices, all operating simultaneously. Of course, you hafta use derivational means to do it, and that's against some religions.

Comment: I don't see anything worthy of a big fuss. In both 1. and 2. "them" is object of "prove" and thus is in accusative case. In 1. "them" is a raised object.

Comment: @StuartF In your examples, the verb "paint" means "cover (something) with paint, or put paint on (something)", so "them" is a semantic argument of the verb "painted", and using the objective case there needs no explaining. Similarly, "call" means "regard or think of (someone or something) in a certain way", so "them" is a semantic argument of "called", and using the objective case there needs no explaining, either. But in "I proved them wrong", "prove" means "to show that (someone or something) has a particular quality", so "them" is not a semantic argument of "proved".

Comment: Where is there a **finite** clause licensing a pronoun in subject case? We can't use subject case otherwise, which is a marked form reserved for that situation only.

Comment: @tchrist We can say _I proved they were wrong_, which means the same thing as (1) or (2). We can explain (1) with 'raising', but how can we explain (2)?...is the question.

Comment: @JK2 This isn’t some syntactic property peculiar to *prove*, you know. You can just as easily say *I considered him eager, I saw him furious, I wanted him fired, I dreamt him happy, I feared him hungry, I needed him gone, I needed him promoted, I needed him laughing, I found him charming, I thought him a beast, I believed him lost, I deemed him worthy, I declared him king, I imagined him winning, I elected him president.*

Comment: @tchrist I didn't say this is "some syntactic property peculiar to _prove_", you know. I've just presented _prove_ as an example of this "syntactic property".

Comment: @tchrist The same question can be asked for all your examples as well, perhaps except for _I dreamt him happy_, which I don't think I would use myself.

Comment: @JK2 Then consider Julius Caesar, and dreaming him alive today.

Comment: @tchrist Somehow, that's fine with me. How strange. Anyway, you get the point, don't you?

Comment: How to explain: *Them* is an object complement? *Prove* is a factitive verb? The subjective *they* as in *\*I proved they wrong* doesn't work?

Comment: @TinfoilHat It is not _them_ but _wrong_ that is an object complement. The subjective _they_ does work in _I proved they were wrong_.

Comment: Yes, of course, my typo. *Them* is the object of *proved* — just like your *that*-clause is the object of *proved* in *I proved [that] they were wrong.* *They* has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @TinfoilHat The whole point of the question was that the syntactic object _them_ is not a semantic object of _proved_.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin If you're familiar with the concepts of Raising and ECM, the question should be clear as day. Normally, linguists use example sentences like (1) when discussing Raising or ECM. But in the literature, rarely do they use sentences like (2) when discussing Raising or ECM. So I was wondering why that is. If sentences like (2) _can_ be explained using Raising/ECM, there must be some linguists who did so. If they cannot be explained using either, I'd like to know how else they can.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin What's that got anything to do with the question?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin It's a fairly simple question, if you understand Raising/ECM.

Comment: Thanks and my only point is that it's a much more simple Question than you seem to realise. That's all I'm trying to say, however poorly…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin If it's that simple, why don't you take a crack at it yourself? Unless and until you show me your own answer, I can't really buy your claim.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I'm asking about 'them' because the example sentences in the OP have 'them', not 'you' or 'him'. So I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Apparently, you don't know a thing about Raising or ECM, and you don't intend to learn about them. No wonder you don't understand the gist of the question.

Answer (score -2):

The OED gives this meaning of "to prove"

**5.a.** transitive. **To show the existence or reality of; to give demonstration or proof of by action; to evince. ... to demonstrate (some quality or condition ...).**

The answer to “What did you prove?” is = “I proved [that] they were wrong.” -> “I proved them [to be] wrong.”

“that they were wrong” is a content clause and the object of “proved”. Because it is a clause “they” remains in the subject case as it is the subject of “were”.

However, when “[that] they were wrong” is reduced to “them wrong”, because “they” is no longer the subject of a verb, “them wrong” becomes the object and “they” changes to the object case, i.e. them.

Comment: How about "them to be wrong", where there is a verb?

Comment: Ordinary English. The Devil made me do it. I painted it green.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Hmm. No, not really. Reason is that in "I painted it green" the word "it" is semantically like the patient argument of *paint*. Indeed, you could easily just say "He painted it". The same is not true of the non-resultative *prove*. In "I proved them wrong" it is not the case that "I proved them" and nor is *them* semantically the patient of "prove"

Comment: "That they were wrong" is complement of "prove", but not object. "Them" is in accusative case because in both examples it is the object of "prove". "Them" is a raised object in 1.

Comment: I don't think 5.a. is the correct definition corresponding to "I proved them wrong". Rather, it's a definition for sentences like "I proved his guilt".

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. If you say "them to be wrong", then this is preceded by a preposition which will cause "them" rather than "they".

Comment: @Greybeard I don't understand. Where's the preposition in "*I proved them to be wrong*"?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Sorry, your comment lacked context and was ambiguous. I was assuming that "them to be wrong" was a fronting adverbial.